# Как заменить любой подмассив Numpy массива на первое число в нем?

Tags: python, numpy

Например

```
a = array([[[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)

b = array([[0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0]],dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. У вас трехмерный массив, но я не вижу здесь разбиение внутри его на матрицы, т.е. я вижу только пока внутри массив состоящий из 3-х столбцов 6 строк.

Comment: например, так: `a[:,0]`